# merge /var with /

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, partition

My ubuntu desktop got `/boot/` full of old kernels which caused `update-initramfs` to fail, which caused `/var` to get full with `/var/tmp/mkinitramfs*` files.

The problem is that both `/boot`, `/var` are separate partitions, so  `apt`, `dpkg` will not work while `/var` is full, thus I can't free up space.

```
filesystem         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev               7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /dev
tmpfs              1,6G   18M  1,6G   2% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p1      19G  2,3G   16G  13% /
/dev/nvme0n1p3      92G  9,0G   78G  11% /usr
tmpfs              7,9G   34M  7,8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs              5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs              7,9G     0  7,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p2     369M  353M     0 100% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p4     189M  3,4M  185M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/sda1          9,1G  9,1G     0 100% /var
/dev/sda3          1,8T   72G  1,7T   5% /home
/dev/loop0          87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/4486
/dev/loop1          87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/4571
/dev/loop2         175M  175M     0 100% /snap/atomify/153
tmpfs              1,6G   80K  1,6G   1% /run/user/1000
/home/kg/.Private  1,8T   72G  1,7T   5% /home/kg
/dev/sdb1          932G  489G  444G  53% /media/kg/Elements
/dev/sdc1          7,4G  7,0G  400M  95% /media/kg/ZOTACWINUSB
```

I am thinking of merging `/var` with `/`. They are on separate disks, os I am actually interested of removing `/var` as partition, I don't care about the remaining unused space.
Do you think that the following procedure is safe?:

1. `sudo mkdir /var2`
2. `sudo cp -a /var/* /var2/`
3. `sudo umount /var`
4. `sudo rm -r /var`
5. `sudo mv /var2 /var`
6. Edit fstab, comment out the mount point for /var
7. `reboot`

If not, could you think of a safer solution?

Comment: Your /var is using 9GB, which is around 7GB more than a normal /var. Try to find out what's filling it up. If you move it to /, you'll only have 5GB left and that might not last long if more stuff is added to /var.

Comment: have you tried apt autoremove and autoclean?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick good point about '/' having little space. The `/var/` is getting full of `update-initramfs` garbage as I explain above. I suppose I should merge `/boot` with `/` instead, or just clean up linux-images more often. Thanks for your comment

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte `autoremove` does not work when `/var` is full. I did clean the cache but was only 30M :)  Anyway cleaning the /var/tmp/* as Stephen suggested was safe indeed, so the situation has been temporarily fixed. Thanks for your comment

Comment: I meant to write `/boot` with `/usr` above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deleting the temporary files seems safer to me:

```
rm /var/tmp/mkinitramfs*
```

You’ll no doubt find files under `/var/cache` and `/var/log` which can be deleted too.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the packages with old kernel versions too. I think, you using the newest one.

Comment: That was my goal, but `apt`, `dpkg` don't work while `/var` is full